# What dataset quality do i need for feeding to CNN? (Sign Language Recognition Project)

Tags: image, dataset, conv-neural-network

I have an CNN project and need an image dataset to train and test, and the problem is my machine can't train huge image dataset with a big resolution. so i decide to capture all my own dataset at **200 x 200 pixel** with my laptop camera using **openCV**.

[This is the example of the captured dataset (200 X 200 pixels)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bEhA.png)

**my question is whether the image quality like this is enough to use for CNN to train ?**

Comment: what exactly do you want to train? If you want to train a detection network to detect a tiny scratch on the nails, then probably 200x200 isnt enough. If you want to claffify whether the image is a hand or isnt a hand, 200x200 pixel is probably enough.

Comment: hello @Micka thanks for the answer, my task are sign language recognition. so i need to train to detect sign language alphabet from A-Z with a hand gesture (Static Sign Language Detection and Recognition)

Comment: might or might not work. I think you will have to test it yourself.